# Casting to arbitrary type in Typed Racket folding a Tree

Tags: tree, racket, fold, parametric-polymorphism, typed-racket

I'm trying to produce a typed Racket procedure that for some type `A`, takes a `Tree`, and a function from two `A`s to an `A`, another parameter of type `A`, and returns a value of type `A`. I'm not very familiar with the `(All)` syntax, but I tried using it. Unfortunately, my code produces the following error message at build-time:

```
Type Checker: Polymorphic function `foldr' could not be applied to arguments:
Types: (-> a b b) b (Listof a)  -> b
       (-> a b c c) c (Listof a) (Listof b)  -> c
       (-> a b c d d) d (Listof a) (Listof b) (Listof c)  -> d
Arguments: (-> A A A) A (Listof Any)
Expected result: A
```

My code:

```
(: fold : (All (A) (Instance Tree) (A A -> A) A -> A))
(define (fold tree f base)
  (foldr
    f
    base
    (cons
      (value tree)
      (map 
        (lambda
          ([tree : (Instance Tree)])
          (fold tree f base)
          ) 
        (children tree)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

I tried to simplify the function until it started to work, and this was where it started working:

```
(: fold : (All (A) (Instance Tree) (A A -> A) A -> A))
(define (fold tree f base)
  (foldr f base (list base))
)
```

I think what's happening is that the type checker doesn't know that `(value tree)` is also of type `A`. Is there any way I can `(Cast)` it to be of type `A`? If not, how would I approach getting this to work?

Comment: You need to include the "Tree" type in your question, it's not built into Typed Racket. More generally, I'm wondering if you really want to be using classes & objects; that's probably going to bring an enormous amount of complexity into this problem. (Pardon me for assuming this is homework but) If the problem statement requires classes or provides this code, then sure, you're stuck with it, but if not, have you considered just using structs?

Answer (score 1):

Without the definition of the `Tree` type it's hard to answer this question.  But the answer in general is not to cast, but to have a type which is a tree *of* nodes which are of some type.  I don't understand classes in Racket, least of all their interaction with typed Racket (which seems to be all subject to change), but here is how you do that with `struct`s, which are well-supported in typed Racket:

```
(struct (A) tree
  ((value : A)
   (children : (Listof (Treeof A))))
  #:type-name Treeof)
```

And now I can check this:

```
> (tree 1 (list (tree -1 '())))
- : (Treeof (U Negative-Fixnum One))
#<tree>
> (tree 1 (list (tree 'x '())))
- : (Treeof (U 'x One))
#<tree>
```

OK, the types its working out are a little unhelpful, but they're correct.

Once you've done this, then it knows nice things about `tree-value` and `tree-children`:

```
> tree-value
- : (All (A) (-> (Treeof A) A))
#<procedure:tree-value>
> tree-children
- : (All (A) (-> (Treeof A) (Listof (Treeof A))))
#<procedure:tree-children>
```

And that's enough to write your function (I'm not sure it is correct, but its types now makes sense):

```
(: fold-tree (All (A) (-> (Treeof A) (-> A A A) A A)))
(define (fold-tree tree f base)
  (foldr f base
         (cons
          (tree-value tree)
          ;; I don't know why it needs this since it knows about tree-children
          (map (λ ((child : (Treeof A)))
                 (fold-tree child f base))
               (tree-children tree)))))
```

Note that for some reason it can't work out that `child` in `(map (λ (child) ...) (tree-children tree))` is a `(Treeof A)` even though it knows that `tree` is and it knows what `tree-children` does.  So I had to tell it that (an older version was buggy and used `tree` instead of `child`, which concealed this problem.

Comment: try `(define (fold-tree tree f base) (f (tree-value tree) (foldr (λ (child r) (fold-tree child f r)) base (tree-children tree))))`. does it work? I expect its type to be `(: fold-tree (All (A R) (-> (Treeof A) (-> A R R) R R)))` (if that's the right way to write it down...)  ---- also, you have a typo, it should have been `(fold-tree child f base)` inside the lambda.

Comment: @WillNess: Your version is at least properly typed, but you need lots of explicit types around the `lambda` (I'm not sure why).  Thanks for finding the bug in my transliteration of OP's, which means I now also need types around the `lambda`.  Either I am missing something or static type systems and me simply do not get on.  (Also, what is it with Racket not warning on unused bindings?  Seriously, it's 1975 already.)

Comment: you can simplify that type down to the one that you had. maybe it won't need as much annotations then.

Comment: @WillNess: it looks as if `(map (lambda (x) ...) y)` loses information about the type of the elements of `y`, even when (I think) it should be able to know it.

Comment: I meant in my version. there's no `map` there. :)

Comment: @WillNess: Doh, sorry.  But no, you still need annotations in the arguments to `lambda`.  With those annotations it not only passes the type checker, it actually works properly.  I might ask a question about this as I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: I've just tried it too. it _loaded_ with the full type when I only added this annotation: `(lambda ((child : (Treeof A)) (r : R)) ...`, and then `(fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) + 0)` even worked and returned 3... but `(fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda (a r) (+ a r)) 0)` gave lots of errors. My Racket version is pretty old though, like, extremely old.

Comment: for the folding of this same data type involving `map`, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222443/understanding-foldtree-functions-type-derivation). there's no place for `base` there at all, as `(tree val (list))` (or equivalently `(Node val [])`) is not empty -- it has `val` in it.

Answer (score 1):

With the struct type definition as in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67159287/849891) by [tfb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5920214/tfb),

```lisp
#lang typed/racket

(struct (A) tree
  ((value : A)
   (children : (Listof (Treeof A))))
  #:type-name Treeof)
```

the following definition works (somewhat):

```lisp
(: fold-tree (All (A R) (-> (Treeof A) (-> A R R) R R)))
(define (fold-tree tree f base)
  (f (tree-value tree)
     (foldr
          (lambda ((child : (Treeof A)) (r : R))
            (fold-tree child f r))
          base
          (tree-children tree))))
```

Now trying it in the interactions window,

```lisp
(fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) + 0)
```

works and returns

```
- : Integer [more precisely: Nonnegative-Integer]
3
```

but trying the seemingly equivalent

```lisp
(fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda (a r) (+ a r)) 0)
```

brings up a lot of errors.

*update:* thanks to tfb's input, the following calls all work:

```
> (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda ((a : Number) (r : Number)) (+ a r)) 0)
- : Number
3

> (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda ((a : Any) (b : Any)) (cons a b)) 0)
- : (U Zero (Pairof Any Any))
'(1 2 . 0)

> (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda ((a : Any) (b : Any)) (cons a b)) '())
- : (U Null (Pairof Any Any))
'(1 2)

> (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda ((a : Any) (b : (Listof Any)))
     (cons a b)) '())
- : (Listof Any)
'(1 2)

> (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda ((a : Number) (b : (Listof Number))) 
     (cons a b)) '())
- : (Listof Number)
'(1 2)

> (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) (lambda (a b) (cons a b)) '())
- : (U Null (Pairof Any Any))
'(1 2)

> (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 '()))) cons '())
*** Type Checker: Polymorphic function `fold-tree' could not be applied to arguments:
Argument 1:
  Expected: (Treeof A)
  Given:    (Treeof Positive-Byte)
Argument 2:
  Expected: (-> A R R)
  Given:    (All (a b) (case-> (-> a (Listof a) (Listof a)) (-> a b (Pairof a b))))
Argument 3:
  Expected: R
  Given:    Null
 in: (fold-tree (tree 1 (list (tree 2 (quote ())))) cons (quote ()))
>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to decorate it as `(fold-tree ... (lambda ((x : Number) (y : Number)) (+ x y)) 0)`, say (this is in Racket 8.0).  It looks like typed Racket is unable to make inferences about types in things like (f ... (lambda (x) ...)), I presume because by the time it's doing its thing it can only see the function object, not the source that gave rise to it (but I don't know).

Comment: @tfb thanks, I've updated the answer with more working annotations examples. interestingly, with `cons` it's the opposite: doesn't work with naked `cons`, does work with `cons` wrapped in an un-annotated lambda!